# Identity concerning $e^{ia\sin{x}}$ as a series of bessel functions

Tags: special-functions

Prove the following identity:

\begin{equation}
e^{ia\sin{x}}=\sum_{-\infty}^{+\infty}J_k(a) e^{ikx},
\end{equation}

where $a$ is a real constant and $J_k$ is the Bessel function of the first type of order $k$.

Comment: This was already bumped by Community, so I took the opportunity to make anotherwise way too minor a correction and upvoted vesszabo'z solution along the way :-)

Answer (score 1):

We know that 
$$
\exp\left[\frac{z}{2}\left( t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}J_k(z)t^k,
$$
using this your identity follows. See e.g. [Properties in Wikipedia and references therein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).